# Can I type input from keyboard to Scanner.nextLine() waiting in .class file by Runtime class?

Tags: java

```java
//Run App from Path
public static void runApp(String path) throws IOException {
    Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process = runTime.exec(path); 
    InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream); 

    int n1;
    char[] c1 = new char[1024];
    StringBuffer standardOutput = new StringBuffer(); 

    while ((n1 = isr.read(c1)) > 0) {
        standardOutput.append(c1, 0, n1); 
    }
    System.out.println("Standard Output: " + standardOutput.toString()); 
}

//Main Method
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String path = "java -classpath E:\\code\\java\\ctppmhw\\bin\\ App";
    runApp(path);  
}
```

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("String is: " + str);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

When I run the main method contains runApp() method, it's waiting for me to type from the keyboard, but I can't type it on my console. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RunApp(main process) starts App.main(sub process), by

```
Process process = runTime.exec(path); 
InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
```

process.inputStream, process.errorStream is (sub process)'s standard output and error output. you can't use them to write back to (sub process) within (main process),
you may try (sub process)process.outputStream.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I modified my code by adding OutputStream and DataOutputStream(named dos), then invoke dos.write(str) and dos.close(). It's work!

Answer (score 1):

I added this code into the above code block and it works:

```java
OutputStream fos = process.getOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);        

dos.writeBytes("5");
dos.flush();
dos.close();
```